# Python unique concatenate value of a column in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to perform this process, imagine to have the following and I want to obtain **col4**. :

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col 4 | Col 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SF | 123 | QW | QW, BF | 1 |
| SF | 456 | AF | AF | 2 |
| SO | xxx | AF | AF, BF | 3 |
| SO | yyy | GD | GD | 4 |
| SF | 123 | BF | QW, BF | 1 |
| RE | xxx | BF | AF, BF | 5 |

For the purpose of aggragation I'm using these 2 lines of code:

```
df[df['col1']!='SF'].groupby(['Col2']).agg({'Col3' : lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())})
```

```
df[df['col1']=='SF'].groupby(['Col2','Col5']).agg({'Col3':','.join})
```

But I don't know how to put them on df. I tried also a merge but didn't work.
I only hope to have been clear!!

Thanks so much in advance

**EDIT 1**
Sorry for not being clear.
Before to perform any line of code I have *Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5*. ***Col4*** is the **output** I would like to obtain.

Comment: Can you add what you'd like your output to be

Comment: Which columns do you already have? And which do you *want* to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `transform` instead of `agg` to assign back to the original DataFrame:

```
df["Col4"] = df.groupby("Col2")["Col3"].transform(lambda x: ", ".join(x.unique()))
```

Comment: It returns with an error: "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 133028 elements, new values have 133243 elements". I I was thinking to rewrite the question and publish another one, since I could be clearer explaining the issue